# Selecting a Testclass from outside (JUnit Selenium)

Tags: selenium, junit

is there a way to specify Testclasses to run in a JUnit TestSuite from outside?

So that i analyse the parameters in the JUnit TestSuite and run JUnit Tests from selected Classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-Dtest=testclass#testmethod` command line parameter, which you can also pass in Jenkins.